# what is the number of possibilities

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have 9 variables that can vary each from 0 to 100.(natural number).
And the sum of the first 3 should be between 20 and 30.
And the sum of the 9 variables should be equal to 100.
What is the number of possible combination knowing that the 9 variables are independent of each other and not commutative.
Thanks for your help.
ZIed

Sorry I am not familiar with bar summaion, can you add more clarification?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can solve this as a summation over $n=20$ to $n = 30$, of the number of ways that the first 3 variables sum to $n$ and the remaining 6 variables sum to $100 - n$. Are you familiar with the stars and bars construction? It will help you with your summation formula.

The stars and bars construction says that the number of ways to partition an integer $N$ into $k$ positive parts is the number of ways to place $k-1$ bars in distinct positions in between a sequence of $N$ consecutive stars, which is clearly ${N-1} \choose {k-1}$. If you want to partition a non-negative integer $N$ into $k$ non-negative parts, then you can add one to each part and get that the answer is equal to the number of ways to partition integer $N+k$ into $k$ positive parts. You can apply this to your problem for $n=20$ to $n=30$.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with bar summation, can you add more clarification? In addition, what should I do if one of the variable should be between 5 and 50? Thanks

Comment: @ziedhosni Clarification added. I'll need to know which variable needs to be between $5$ and $50$ to answer the second part, it depends on whether the variable is in the first group of 3 or the remaining group of 6.

Comment: Actually, several variable are restained. Let'ts say that this variable is in the first group and another in the second group